# Display XML with jquery mobile - performance?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, jquery-mobile, xpath

I'm developing an app for mobile devices. I'm using jquery mobile and phonegap (to access the internal functions of the device). I have a big xml file with 10 to more than a thousand nodes. Basically I need to display each node on its own page. In jquery mobile it's common practice to build one html file that contains all pages.

I'm playing with the idea to build something like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="1">JS template filled with content of node1 from xml and linking to page 2.</div>
<div data-role="page" id="2">JS template filled with content of node2 from xml and linking to page 3.</div>
```

If I create such a huge page by parsing the XML file with javascript, I'm concerned that the app would be tremendously slow. In my experience browsers cannot handle pages that well, if they are very long. The xml file can contain text, and links to images, video and audiofiles.
I tried to render the xml file via xslt on client-side, but ran into the problem, that most android browsers do not support xsl (at least mine does not).
I need to find a solution on client-side, because the app should work also without internet-connection.

Can you point me to the right direction? Maybe I am wrong and it's no big deal if the main html-file contains a couple of hundred pages? I also had the idea to fetch the pages one by one from the xml, since I don't display more than one page at a time. But I'm not sure how to keep track of the nodes that I have already displayed to the user. The xml file contains no auto-incrementing identifiers. So it would be difficult to access specific nodes in order via xpath, or am I missing out on something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An XML file with a thousand nodes is pretty small by most people's standards (and one with 10 nodes is miniscule), so it's hard to see what your real problem is.

Although some mobile browsers do not have native XSLT support, you could try Saxon-CE which offers an XSLT 2.0 implementation that runs on any Javascript-enabled browser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I know that the xml file is not big. My concern is, that creating the jquery mobile pages from an xml file might take long. The looping & page building process takes time. 
My current solution: 
1. loading the xml file
2. iterating through the file
3. appending each data-role="page" by using a simple JS template engine
but this is too slow. It takes about 10 seconds to load the app with 1000 pages. Once the html is created, the app is running ok.   
Saxon-CE might be a solution, but I prefer to use open source and cost-free solutions.

Comment: Yes, I quite understand, we all prefer someone else to pay for our software! 10 seconds for appending 1000 elements seems absurdly slow, but I'm not familiar with the technology so can't point you at a solution.

Comment: I understand your anger, since you developed Saxon-CE. But please don't take it the wrong way. I'm a student and I do this for a project at university. I pay enough tuition fees and should be able to develop something myself for this small project. I was just looking for a hint if there is something out there that could make it more efficient. I also respected you answer and voted it up. So no need to be angry. If I was developing this app for a huge company I would try Saxon-CE for sure. Of course you could not know this.

Comment: No anger intended. I'm well aware that there are lots of people who can't justify spending money on software. That's why we ship a free version for individuals and small companies. Sorry it doesn't work for your requirements.